Old black & white movie that was a duel of romantic stories
Decades ago a saw the end of an old black and white movie that I am searching for the title of. The concept was a couple trying to tell the most romantic story to a group of girls to see who's was better.  I missed the first story (the female's), but saw the second.  It was about a female doctor in medieval times who saved the king's life and was given the hand of his most charming knight as a reward. The knight married her and then left her, claiming he would never return until she was wearing his family ring.  Later the local gossip tells that he is in another town romancing a young girl. The wife traveled to the town and fooled the husband into thinking he was with his new love for a night. She left the town the next day with his ring. He confronts her months later after finding out that his wife is pregnant, only to realize the full story.

That's pretty much the plot of Shakespeare's All’s Well That Ends Well (though that was also based on Decameron). What was the country\language?

That is All's Well That Ends Well.  And the 1968 version is in black and white. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0062651

Although the plot for the second story followed the Shakespeare play, that was only the second part of the movie.  I missed the first story in the movie.  The movie was also not in iambic pentameter, but it was in English.  I tend to think it was more American then British, but it has been so many years since I have seen it that I can not be sure.  All's Well That Ends Well is the closest I have come to finding the correct answer.

Inspired by @Walt's comment, I wonder if you're looking for Decameron Nights (1953), starring Joan Fontaine and Louis Jourdan. There are three tales in the movie, of which the third matches your description:

Spanish Don Bertrando (Jourdan) is sent to fetch a female doctor, Isabella (Fontaine), for his master, the seriously ill King (Hugh Morton). On the trip, he has to defend her against two highwaymen.
When she is able to cure the King, he offers her anything she wants. She asks for a husband: Bertrando. Dismayed, Bertrando agrees, but immediately after their wedding, he leaves her, as that was all that he had promised to do, and resumes his playboy ways. Before he departs, he tells his new wife that he will only live with her if she obtains the ring on his finger and bears him a child. Determined, she sets out to do just that.
Learning that Bertrando is trying to seduce an innkeeper's daughter Maria (Joan Collins), Isabella has the aggrieved innkeeper send Bertrando a message supposedly from Maria agreeing to spend the night with him. Instead, Isabella keeps the rendezvous in the dark, unlit bedroom. She later steals Bertrando's ring while he is sleeping and leaves before her deception is revealed. Months later, she gives birth to a son. Bertrando shows up, having heard that she claims the child is his. After she tells her story, Bertrando embraces her.

The framing device matches as well:

In the mid-fourteenth century, Boccaccio seeks his true love, the recently widowed Fiametta (Joan Fontaine), and finds that she has fled Florence, plague-ridden and being sacked by an invading army, for a villa in the countryside with several female companions. When he shows up on her doorstep, Fiametta does not want to invite him to stay, but her friends, bored and lacking male companionship, override her objections. To entertain the ladies (and further his courtship of Fiametta), Boccaccio tells stories of the pursuit of love.

The only thing that doesn't match is that it's in color, not black & white.  Still, if you think this might be it, you could try watching the last scene—it appears that the whole thing is up on YouTube (at least for now.)




Very nice answer.
